# Postgres. Error installing my own extension

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install a custom small extension for Postgres just for testing, but I can't do it.

My steps:
1.- Create the *.sql file (**hola.sql**):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION di_hola() 
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'Hola';
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION di_hola()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

2.- Create control file (**hola.control**):

```
# hola extension
comment = 'Funcion para decir hola'
default_version = '1.0'
relocatable = false
```

3.- **Makefile**:

```
EXTENSION = hola
DATA = hola.sql

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

4.- Install it (in my case `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension`)

```
sudo make USE_PGXS=1 install
```

5.- From psql (`psql -U postgres -h localhost -W`)

```
postgres=# create extension hola;
ERROR:  extension "hola" has no installation script nor update path for version "1.0"
```

I can't find many information about this error. The files are properly installed in `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension`

I have Postgres 10 under Linux Mint.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL script for version 1.0 must be called

```
hola--1.0.sql
```