# Create extension from postgres superuser to another database with it own owner?

Tags: postgresql

Maybe I'm saying a silliness, but is it possible to create a extension from a superuser - like postgres - in other database with it own schema and owner?

I have a database called *sdmed*, with two schemas, *public* and *sdmed*. I also have a role called *sdmed* . This role can only create tables.

I would like to create a extension in those database. The extension has functions, tables and types.

If not, what would be the better way to do that?

**Edit:**

My original question was incomplete. I mean that I want to create extension from user postgres (or a superuser) in other database, with it owner, role and schema. Also, those extension would be used in those database.

I try this one:

First, I create a function only for those schema (sdmed is a database, with a schema called sdmed and it owner is sdmed):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sdmed.di_hola() 
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'Hola';
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION sdmed.di_hola()
  OWNER TO sdmed;
```

Also (after [prepare my own extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901605/postgres-error-installing-my-own-extension))

```
postgres=# create extension hola;
ERROR:  schema "sdmed" does not exist
```

(The database role and schema sdmed exists)

And if I try from sdmed database:

```
sdmed=> create extension hola;
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "hola"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

I would make `sdmed` a SuperUser, but I would like to avoid that for keep best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but in case you're wondering if it would somehow make the extension not to work properly the answer is: **it shouldn't be an issue** :)

Since the user `sdmed` is the owner of the database `sdmed`, it has access to all objects in this database - no matter who created them! So, objects installed by the function created with the user `postgres` should work with the user `sdmed` without any problem.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. But from postgres I can't do that. I have edited the question because the first one was incomplete. Anyway....how could do that?

Comment: I see. Have you tried setting the schema of your function? Something like `UPDATE pg_extension SET extrelocatable = TRUE WHERE extname = 'hola';
ALTER EXTENSION hola SET SCHEMA sdmed;`

Comment: Thank you. It was a concept error of mine. I wanted to CREATE EXTENSION being role sdmed and connected to sdmed database. Or being postgres connected to postgres database. So easy like being postgres using sdmed. I'm  sorry for so a silly question, but your answer saying "it shouldn't be an issue" was the clue for dig in that way :-)