# How to fix "extension has no installation script nor update path" error?

Tags: postgresql

I'm maintaining an old [PostgreSQL extension](https://github.com/linz/postgresql-tableversion/pull/383), and trying to [release a new version](https://github.com/linz/postgresql-tableversion/pull/383). The [test script](https://github.com/linz/postgresql-tableversion/blob/8e787e4acc66438ea5a99a22d82f964ec21da481/.github/workflows/test.yml#L45-L79) fails when running `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS table_version version '1.10.3';`:

> ERROR:  extension "table_version" has no installation script nor update path for version "1.10.3"

It is not [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59902476/96588), because [the package](https://packagecloud.io/linz/prod/packages/ubuntu/bionic/postgresql-10-tableversion_1.10.3-linz%7Ebionic_all.deb?distro_version_id=190) (installed successfully in an earlier step in the test script) does contain the relevant `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3.sql` file. I'm stumped for what else could be the issue.

To reproduce:

1. Run `nix-shell --pure --run 'docker build --tag=docker-builder .'` on the "master" branch of of [linz-software-repository](https://github.com/linz/linz-software-repository/) to create the Debian package builder image ([log](https://gist.github.com/l0b0/2ee004982450951b9edfa08224168b08))
2. Run `docker run --env=DRY_RUN=1 --env=GITHUB_REPOSITORY=linz/postgresql-tableversion --env=RUNNER_WORKSPACE="$(dirname "$PWD")" --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker-builder focal jq "$PWD"` on the [postgresql-tableversion](https://github.com/linz/postgresql-tableversion) "release-1.10" branch to create the Debian package ([log](https://gist.github.com/l0b0/b58b43262e84a6111c31d7baaa781096))
3. Run `docker build --build-arg=RELEASE=focal --tag=tester .` to create the test runner Docker image ([log](https://gist.github.com/l0b0/23f757505699808075b4081c2702cb90))
4. Run `docker run --rm --volume="${PWD}/build-area:/packages" tester ./test/ci/package-upgrade.bash 10` to see the error ([log](https://gist.github.com/l0b0/ed8fecbfedced6083819b1d3145b9259)).

Trying the last step manually, the Docker container ends up with these files:

```
root@939371dd2cf4:/src# ls -1 /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version*
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.2--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.2dev--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3dev--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.4--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.4--1.10.4next.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.4next--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--unpackaged--1.10.4.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version.control
```

Possibly related findings:

- The locally built package gets its version number from the latest tag, rather than `EXTVERSION` in the `Makefile`. But creating the new "1.10.4" tag and pushing it doesn't seem to help in any way.
- `apt-get --assume-yes install postgresql-10-tableversion` does create `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3.sql`, but this file is gone after installing the locally built .deb file.

Comment: Is there already a version of the installation installed? Please add the output of `\dx` in `psql` to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's installed 1.10.3. Does that mean `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS table_version '1.10.3`;` will fail? The difference between installing and "creating" an extension is confusing.

Comment: I'm suspecting some kind of permission issue - not sure tho how to troublehoot it

Comment: Confused by *... does contain the relevant /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3.sql *  vs */postgresql/10/extension/table_version--1.10.3.sql, but this file is gone after installing the locally built .deb file.*. What is in `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/` after the local .deb install?